# The inverse of a function f(x) when ff(x) = x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A curve has equation $$ f:x  = \frac{x+3}{2x - 1}, x\neq \frac{1}{2}$$

(i) Show that $f(f(x)) = x$.

(ii) Hence, or otherwise, obtain an expression for $f^{-1} (x)$.

I successfully completed part i. I understand that f(x) is a reflection over the line $y = x = f(f(x))$. I don't know how to obtain a correct expression for $f^{-1}(x)$. Is there some property I am missing here? How would you go about solving this?

I tried switching x and y and solving for y, but did not get the correct answer. Is it because there are two x and I can't apply this technique?

Comment: If $f$ is a bijection and $f(f(x))=x$ then $f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Not super related to the question at hand but good reading: such $f$ are called involutions if you would like to know more.

Comment: Kavi's comment is the most straightforward way of deducing this. Regardless,
>"I tried switching x and y and solving for y, but did not get the correct answer"
Well, you must have made a mistake. It follows quite easily that since $2xy-y=x+3\iff 2xy-x=y+3\iff x=\frac{y+3}{2y-1}$, therefore $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+3}{2x-1}=f(x)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What's a bijection? I googled and it said "one-to-one" function. Is that correct?

Comment: @highgardener So you solved for x and THEN switched x and y? That's what I must have done wrong.

Comment: Bijection means one-to-one and onto.

Comment: @Trying yes, that is how to write out the inverse. Note that in the process I divided by $2y-1$. I can do that since for no values of $x$ can $y$ attain that value as you can verify.

Comment: @Trying If you don't know what a bijection is, how do you define $f^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I do know what a one-to-one function is, and that a function must be 1:1 for it to have an inverse, but was not taught to call it a 'bijection'. I know now, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without delving into the heavier mathematics, if you have a function $y = f(x)$, then the process to find the function inverse is as follows

(1) Rearrange $ y = f(x) $ into the form $x = g(y)$

(2) Replace $y$ with $x$ in $g(y)$ to form the inverse: $f^{-1}(x) = g(x)$